# hide navigation bar in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Title says it all. I'm trying to hide the address and tab bar in firefox such that it only shows up when I press Ctrl+L. Similar to the way it auto hides in full screen mode. I found a whole bunch of discontinued extensions, but no luck with something that still works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a solution. Go to about:config. Set full-screen-api.ignore-widgets to true. Then you can press f11 to hide all ui elements. You will loose the full screen mode though.

Comment: Oh my godnesses, where did you find that information? Cannot beleave how much time I spent on finding any good infos and ended up writing a userChrome.css and now it turns out, a single config-setting makes about all of the deal for me; Thank you loads of much!

Comment: The only caveat for me is, that focusing the address-bar, or opening a new tab, will show the top-bar permanently, so you have to hit F11 again. As you don't want to loose fullscreen-mode, maybe running firefox in kiosk-mode. can bring you the wished result? You can run it of the commandline with `firefox --kiosk`

Comment: This needs to be more visible! I was looking for exactly that functionality for ages.

Comment: @Ida I installed auto fullscreen addon with this config. Now everything works perfectly as expected for me. 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/i-auto-fullscreen/

Comment: Still working in 2024.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution without loosing the full screen mode, is the way it is handled in the [Mint WebApp](https://github.com/linuxmint/webapp-manager).

- Create a `chrome` folder in your firefox profile folder
- Place a `userChrome.css` file within this folder
- And add the following content to the file

```
#nav-bar, #identity-box, #tabbrowser-tabs, #TabsToolbar {
    visibility: collapse !important;
}
```

- You can also only hide the navigation bar or the tabs bar by removing some of the keywords
- This way you can make your browser look like an app

Answer (score 0):

I tried a number of solutions. Nothing worked for my liking. I found this css config does exactly what I want.

This one needs to be added in `userChrome.css`

https://github.com/MrOtherGuy/firefox-csshacks/blob/master/chrome/autohide_toolbox.css

It autohides address bar, navigation bar and bookmarks bar unit. It shows them when `ctrl + l` is pressed.

I also hide tabs along this and use only tree style tabs.